# How can I find out if a List of Maps contain a specific value for key?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble understanding how to check if a List of Maps contain a value by a key. Below is the structure of data I have.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    bookTxt: Hereissomebooktext.,
    bookAuth: Charles
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    bookTxt: Hereissomemorebooktext.,
    bookAuth: Roger
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    bookTxt: Hereissomeevenmorebooktext.,
    bookAuth: Matt
  }
]
```

I'm trying to write something simple or a function to see if this List of Maps contains a certain 'id'. I know that List has the Contains method but in my case I have to find a value within a list of Maps.

For example if I want to see if the List of Maps above contains the `id` of `3`, how would I be able to access that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Direct way to check

```
if (list[0].containsKey("id")) {
  if (list[0]["id"] == 3) {
    // your list of map contains key "id" which has value 3
  }
}
```

And for indirect way you need to iterate through the loop like this:

```dart
for (var map in list) {
  if (map?.containsKey("id") ?? false) {
    if (map!["id"] == 3) {
      // your list of map contains key "id" which has value 3
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, if map["id"] == 3, how can i remove that map from my list?

Comment: @KamrulHasanJony In above if condition i.e.`if (map['id'] == 3)`, use `list.remove(map)`.

Comment: how can I check if the list of maps does not contain an id '2' for example ?

each map in the loop will return false for map['id'] == 2 ,, but I want to know that the entire list does not contain id = '2',, its kinda confusing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe iterating over the maps in the list, then ask to every map to get key you want, and check the content for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for necro'ing this a bit, but wouldn't it be more intuitive and straightforward to use `any()` on the list? You also get the negative case as commented on.

```
bool hasThreeID = myList.any((mapTested) => mapTested['id'] == 3);
```

You can also use `removeWhere()` instead of `any()` for removal.